# Why are types sometimes given as template arguments, other times as type aliases?

Tags: rust

Below is a snippet from [Tokio-util sources](https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio/blob/master/tokio-util/src/codec/encoder.rs#L8-L15).

[image]

I've noticed that sometimes trait authors use `<Item>` and other times type aliases (like `Error`, here). In particular, the corresponding [decoder sources](https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio/blob/master/tokio-util/src/codec/decoder.rs#L35-L37) have `Item` as a type alias.

What does this imply to the reader?

Comment: `Item` is a generic type and `Encoder::Error` is an [associated type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/generics/assoc_items/types.html). (And Rust doesn't have templates.)

Comment: Thanks for marking this as a duplicate. I read that entry and now have some idea.